# Can I create a set of repeated rows and panels using two dependent variables?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have the prometheus metric `node_hwmon_temp_celsius` which has the relevant labels `chip` and `sensor`.

For example, `chip` might be `nvme_nvme0` or `platform_coretemp_0` and sensor might be `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3`, ...

I've created two variables in Grafana:

- `chip` which is defined as `label_values(node_hwmon_temp_celsius{job="$job"}, chip)`
- `sensor` which is defined as `label_values(node_hwmon_temp_celsius{job="$job",chip=~"$chip"}, sensor)`

As you can see, `sensor` depends on the value of `chip`. I have defined my row to repeat by `chip` and my panel within that row to repeat by `sensor`.

If I select "All" on `chip` then I get multiple `chip` rows, but the panels are repeated for every `sensor` across any chip, for example:

Row: `chip="nvme_nvme0"` contains 24 panels (but there are only 3 nvme temps):
`chip="nvme_nvme0", "sensor="temp1..24"}`

Row `chip="platform_coretemp_0"` contains 24 panels (because 24 CPU cores):
`chip="platform_coretemp_0", "sensor="temp1..24"}`

I completely understand **why** this is happening, it's because the `sensor` value is just picking up all the possible values on a dashboard level for any chip value.

My desired behaviour is:

Row: `chip="nvme_nvme0"` contains 3 panels:
`chip="nvme_nvme0", "sensor="temp1..3"}`

Row `chip="platform_coretemp_0"` contains 24 panels:
`chip="platform_coretemp_0", "sensor="temp1..24"}`

That is, I want to only repeat panels for the `chip/sensor` pairs that have data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do so.

Two easily imaginable way to achieve something like that would be:

1. Value of `sensor` withing row recalculated for corresponding `chip`.
   Nothing of the similar manner is implemented, and I doubt that ever be: rather convoluted logic of variable dependencies will cause more problems, then it solves.
2. Conditional hiding of panel.
   There were a couple questions about hiding panel based on value or query conditions here and at Grafana's communities, but AFAIK, they are unresolved as of now.

In my opinion best course of action, available at this point, is to use single dimensional repeat: Use repeat panel over `chip` and show every `sensor` on this single panel. This way you'll have built-in hiding on non-existent `chip`-`sensor` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp in the sensor variable configuration to select only values, which contain 'temp'. Eventually you can add regexp condition to you query, that sensor must contain 'temp'

If you don't need a timeseries, then I would use table panel and your setup will be simplified - just one query with grouping by chip and sensor.

Comment: Row most certainly does have a repeat by variable option. I'm using it right now, as stated in the question. I accept that it might not be possible, but if it's impossible it's not because you can't repeat rows by variable.

And yes, I want a timeseries, but thanks for the table suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisYoung you are right. answer updated

Comment: Unfortunately your updated answer doesn't solve the problem. If you mean add `,sensor=~"temp.*"` or similar, that doesn't make any difference. The problem is that there are 3 sensor values for chip="nvme_nvme0" (being temp1, temp2, temp3) and 24 sensor values for chip="platform_coretemp_0" (being temp1, temp2, ... temp24). So if I set the variable chip to all chips then I get two rows, but each of them has 24 panels because the sensor variable has temp values from 1  to 24 despite there only being 3 for nvme_nvme_0. Instead, I want one row with 3 panels and one row with 24 panels.